# Unable to Save Log File from Powershell Command in Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

I am trying to create a log file from a Powershell task in `Task Scheduler` but, nothing that I try is working.

**Program/script**

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

**Add arguments**

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\Users\Boston\script.ps1" > C:\Users\Boston\script.log
```

This is not saving the output of the task to a file.

Comment: How are you running the task and with what privileges? Check the permissions on the file are available to the task. Might be better for you to use a Start-Transcript in your actual script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get any output because you are passing the redirection as an argument to powershell.exe because the redirection isn't interpreted by a cmd prompt. e.g.

**Executable:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

**Argument List:**

```
-ExecutionPolicy 
Unrestricted 
-File 
"C:\Users\Boston\script.ps1" 
> 
C:\Users\Boston\script.log
```

In order to log output, the best way is to do it within the script. But, you can work around it by running the script as a `-Command` and then use PowerShell itself to redirect the output for you:

**Arguments:**

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& C:\Users\Boston\script.ps1 > C:\Users\Boston\script.log"
```